# Computing Gradients of Weighted State Averages in PyTorch Models

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, autograd, automatic-differentiation, autodiff

I have two trained models with the same architecture and different performances. I want to construct a new model by taking the weighted average of their states (s1, s2, s1+s2=1) and calculate the gradients of the new model's loss with respect to s1 and s2. Here's my current approach:

1. Create a simple model:

   ```py
   import torch
   import torch.nn as nn

   class MultiplyByWeight(nn.Module):
       def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
           super(MultiplyByWeight, self).__init__()
           self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, output_size)

       def forward(self, x):
           return self.linear(x)
   ```
2. Define the states:

   ```py
   state_1 = {
       'linear.weight': 2.4,
       'linear.bias': 0.1
   }
   state_2 = {
       'linear.weight': 0,
       'linear.bias': -0.5,
   }
   ```
3. Set the weights of the states:

   ```py
   state_weights = torch.tensor([0.5, 0.5], requires_grad=True)
   ```
4. Set the weighted average of the states as the new model's state. I encountered a problem here: when I update the state_dict or modify the named_parameters, the tensors are treated as leaf nodes and detached, losing the computation graph needed to calculate gradients with respect to state_weights.

   - With load_state_dict:

     ```py
     d = model.state_dict()
     for k in d:
         d[k] = d[k] + state_1[k] * state_weights[0] + state_2[k] * state_weights[1]
     model.load_state_dict(d)
     ```
   - With named_parameters:

     ```py
     for k, param in model.named_parameters():
         param.data.add_(state_1[k] * state_weights[0])
         param.data.add_(state_2[k] * state_weights[1])
     ```
5. Calculate loss and gradients:

   ```py
   def loss_pt(y_hat, y):
       return (y_hat - y) ** 2

   r = model(torch.tensor([1.]))
   l = loss_pt(r, 2)
   l.backward()
   state_weights.is_leaf, state_weights.grad
   # (True, None)
   ```

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions on how to tackle this issue. I tried searching for a quick workaround in the PyTorch source code, but it doesn't seem to be a straightforward approach.